# Show that $d(\omega ∧ \tau ) = (d\omega)∧\tau +(−1)^{\text{deg}\omega} w ∧d\tau.$

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, exterior-derivative

> The exterior differentiation $d : \Omega^∗(U)→\Omega^∗(U)$ is an
>   antiderivation of degree $1$: $$d(\omega ∧ \tau ) = (d\omega)∧\tau
>  +(−1)^{\text{deg}\omega} w ∧d\tau.$$

Suppose $\omega=\sum a_Idx^I$ and $\tau=\sum b_Jdx^J$

$d(\omega ∧ \tau )=d(\sum_{I\cap J=\phi} a_Ib_Jdx^I\wedge dx^J).$

$=\sum_{I\cap J=\phi} d(a_Ib_J)\wedge (dx^I\wedge dx^J)$

$=\sum_{I\cap J$=\phi} \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\partial(a_Ib_J)}{\partial x^k}dx^k \wedge (dx^I\wedge dx^J) $

$=\sum_{I\cap J=\phi} \sum_{k=1}^n(a_I\frac{\partial(b_J)}{\partial x^k}+\frac{\partial(a_I)}{\partial x^k}b_J)dx^k \wedge (dx^I\wedge dx^J) $

$=\sum_{I\cap J=\phi} \sum_{k=1}^n(a_I\frac{\partial(b_J)}{\partial x^k}+\frac{\partial(a_I)}{\partial x^k}b_J)dx^k \wedge dx^I\wedge dx^J$

$=\sum_{I\cap J=\phi} \sum_{k=1}^n a_I\frac{\partial(b_J)}{\partial x^k}dx^k \wedge dx^I\wedge dx^J+ \sum_{I\cap J=\phi} \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\partial(a_I)}{\partial x^k}b_J dx^k \wedge dx^I\wedge dx^J$

........................................................................................................................................................

$= \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\partial(b_J)}{\partial x^k}dx^k\sum_{I\cap J=\phi}a_I \wedge dx^I\wedge dx^J+ \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\partial(a_I)}{\partial x^k}dx^k \sum_{I\cap J=\phi}b_J   \wedge dx^I\wedge dx^J$

Am I correct? how do I complete the proof? Please help me.

Comment: I think I tried to move the indices in adjacent transpositions, each move resulted in a minus sign and then the signature of the overall permutation equaled some function of the degree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct.

To complete the proof, in the first summand of your last line, permute $dx^{I}$ to the left so that it is adjacent to $a_{I}$.

In the second summand, move $b_{J}$ to the right so that it is adjacent to $dx^{J}$.

Comment: $= \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\partial(b_J)}{\partial x^k}dx^k\sum_{I\cap J=\phi}a_I \wedge dx^I\wedge dx^J+ \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\partial(a_I)}{\partial x^k}dx^k \sum_{I\cap J=\phi}b_J   \wedge dx^I\wedge dx^J$

Comment: Let me complete the answer using your hint. Can you please verify?

Comment: The idea is to get the objects with $J$s together, and the objects with $I$ together. Try calculating $d\omega\wedge\tau$ and $\omega\wedge d\tau$ so you see what you need to aim for. :) Also remember to add the signs coming from the premutations @FailedtobeaMathematician

Comment: okay Thank you. Let me Try :)

Comment: Right. If you have problems we can go to the chat. But yes! try it yourself first.

Comment: Yes! I got that. Thank you very much.:)